# DoublyLinkedList remove error

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Im making a doublyLinkedList.  The error is to do with my Remove method.  I cant figure this out.  does anyone know?

Here is where the error is?

> Error 1   error C2027: use of undefined type
>   'DoublyListNode'    c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++\projects\repeat
>   - doublylinkedlist\repeat - doublylinkedlist\doublylinkedlist.h   230 1   Repeat - DoublyLinkedList

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Remove
//  Description:    Removes the node that the iterator points to, moves iterator forward to the next node.
//  Arguments:      p_iterator: The iterator to remove
//                  isForward: Tells which direction the iterator was going through the list
//  Return Value:   None.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Remove(DoublyListIterator<Datatype>& m_itr)
{
    DoublyListNode<Datatype>* node = m_head;
    // if the iteratordoesn’t belong to this list, do nothing.
    if (m_itr.m_list != this)
        return;
    // if node is invalid, do nothing.
    if (m_itr.m_node == 0)
        return;
    if (m_itr.m_node == m_head)
    {
        // move the iteratorforward and delete the head.
        m_itr.Forth();
        RemoveHead();
        m_size--;
    }
    else
    {
        // scan forward through the list until you find
        // the node prior to the node you want to remove
        while (node->m_next != m_itr.m_node)
            node = node->m_next;
        // move the iterator forward.
        m_itr.Forth();
        // if the node you are deleting is the tail,
        // update the tail node.
        if (node->m_next == m_tail)
        {
            m_tail = node;
        }
        // delete the node.
        delete node->m_next;
        // re-link the list.
        node->m_next = m_itr.m_node;
        m_size--;
    }
}
```

If anymore code is needed just ask.  I do not want to put lots of code on Stack overflow users.

Comment: what exactly is the error you're seeing?  ex: compiler/linker, undesired runtime behavior (be specific)?  Or SEGFAULT?

Comment: Do you really expect to get any help without even telling us what the error is? We don't need more code right now, we need a proper title and a question.

Comment: apoogies.  I copied and pasted the title.  I made a mistake when doing this.  i edited my code.  Could you please re think my downvote.

Comment: It's much better now. You'll be able to figure this out yourself, I'm sure. Start by looking at the line the error is referring to. Which one is it?

Comment: Its this: while (node->m_next != m_itr.m_node).  Its to do with the while and its looking for a datatype?

Comment: I've come across this when the proper include file was missing or `DoublyListNode` was typed slightly different in the declaration.

Comment: Good, now go for the types of your variables: What are the types of node, m_next, m_itr and m_node?

Comment: I'm guessing something might be missing here: `void Remove(DoublyListIterator<Datatype>& m_itr)`  especially if this method `Remove` is part of something like `DoublyList`.  Then you'd want something like `void DoublyList::Remove(...)` with the template code above that

Comment: public:
 DoublyListNode<Datatype>* m_head;
 DoublyListNode<Datatype>* m_tail;
 int m_count;
 int m_size;

Comment: @Pendo826: I hope this is not supposed to be an answer to my question. You need to stay focused on the line that produces the error. So what are the types of `node`, `m_next`, `m_itr` and `m_node`? Only if you know that you'll be able to get rid of that compiler error

Comment: @Pendo826 please join me in the chat over here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15809/doublylinkedlist-remove-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for tail node but not for a node between head and a tail.You are breaking the chain by deleting the node even before linking it to the next member.

Let us analyze:-

```
while (node->m_next != m_itr.m_node)
            node = node->m_next;
```

after the loop `node->m_next` points `m_itr.m_node`

```
    delete node->m_next;
    // re-link the list.
    node->m_next = m_itr.m_node;
```

You are assigning a deleted node!!!!

Change the code:-

```
node->m_next = m_itr.m_node;
delete m_itr;
```

Comment: This is more of a compilation error `DoublyListNode<Datatype>*`, you will need to look out your code.I justed pointed out the logic fault.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was a typo of the class DoublyListNode.  The class was names DLNode.  So this gave the error being discussed above.